# How can I classify the values inside an array according to a rule?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array:

```
aCarbs = [31.90, 171, 155, 34, 25, 28, 90, 15]
```

I want to build a function that prints the numbers that are >90.

```
function smallCarbs(){
  if(aCarbs>90){

  }
}
```

I get stuck after that, any ideas?

Comment: This is called "filtering". See [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for one approach (which is more useful when a direct side-effect is not involved).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This'll work everywhere:

```
function smallCarbs(){
  for (var x = 0; x < aCarbs.length; x++) {
    if(aCarbs[x]>90){
      console.log(aCarbs[x]);
    }
  }
}
```